# use of at-spi2 interface for an application running with x11 forwarding over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, dbus

I am connecting to the remote machine as follows:

```
ssh user@host -Y
```

If I run an application, for example `gnome-calculator`, here in my ssh terminal, it runs on my local screen as I wished.

But for a use case (UI Automation) I need to access that application's elements on AT-SPI2.

Even if the app is running on my local screen, it is not shown on the accerciser. (See the attachment)

[image: accerciser]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

D-Bus communications don't go through X11; you'll need to separately forward the relevant sockets. Recent OpenSSH versions have support for AF_UNIX socket forwarding.

1. Find out the remote D-Bus socket address.
2. Choose a temporary local socket path.
3. Use `ssh -L <localpath>:<remotepath> <server>` to forward a locally listening socket to the remote D-Bus socket.
4. Have your program connect to the local socket and SSH will forward it to the remote bus.

From what I know, the AT-SPI bus is discovered by making a call through the session bus, so you might need to repeat the above process twice: first forward the session bus (using $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS to determine its path on the remote system), then forward the AT-SPI bus (after discovering its address through a session-bus call).